# "numCollision" statistics in INET framework

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet, 802.11p

I am currently working on an 802.11p simulator, which makes use of the OMNeT++ and INET simulation frameworks.

I would just like to ask if there's a built-in function to get the "number of collisions" statistics.
I found "numCollision" in BasicStatistics.cc (inet/src/inet/linklayer/ieee80211/mac/). 
However, it seems that it's not yet really implemented, as I could not find where "numCollision" is being incremented in the code and I always get 0 numCollision when running a scenario.

Could you please let me know how to get the "number of collisions" statistics using the INET framework? 
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: If you're using the current master version, you might want to have a look to the code on GitHub -> https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/blob/master/src/inet/linklayer/ieee80211/mac/statistics/BasicStatistics.cc

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I already checked the current version. However, I'm unable to find where exactly is numCollision being incremented. It doesn't seem to be updated in the code. That's why I'm always getting a 0 value when running any scenario. Is there other way to get the "number of collisions" statistic? Thank you.

Comment: Have a look to the code. This BasicStatistics module is not used.

Comment: Hi, yes I can see that. And I also understand that I won't be able to get the number of collisions even with the use of the BasicStatistics module since numCollision is not implemented. I'd like to know if there's an alternative in INET to get the number of collisions automatically. I looked at other simulation frameworks like Veins, and it seems that it is possible there just by enabling it in the omnetpp.ini file. I'd like to ask if the same functionality is available in INET or any other method to get the said statistic. Thank you!